# Terminal crashes on startup (zsh not found)

Tags: gnome-terminal, zsh

Terminal crashes on startup,
I previously install zsh and set it as the default shell

Then, I removed zsh without changing default shell.
please help!!

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You have virtually answered your own question. You probably need to set a new default shell in the same way as you did before. Bash will be found at /bin/bash.

Comment: install zsh or link your profiles to run bash or another shell of your choice. another to do that with good oldies method is setting bash instead of zsh editing from vim /etc/passwd